# How can I get a specific keywords with primary word and optional the others in python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to filter real-time tweets twitter, I have this list keywords=["Alex", "love","hate","hungry","happy"] I want to get tweets that at least has "Alex" and one or more keywords from given list. my code is below when I run it, it tracks the tweet that contains any words from the list. remember again I want "Alex" as the main track keywords in the tweet it should have "Alex" and the rest "love","hate","hungry","happy" are optional track keywords.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
csecret = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
atoken = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
asecret = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        out = open('out1.txt', 'a')
        out.write(tweet.encode('utf-8'))
        out.write('\n')
        out.close()
        print username, " :: ", tweet
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
keywords = ["Alex", "love","hate","hungry","happy"]
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=keywords, languages=["en"])
```

Comment: Do you mean it has to have Alex and 1 of the other options? If so this would likely be the easiest way to go about it result = twitterStream.filter(track=['Alex'], languages=["en"]).filter(track=keywords, languages=["en"])

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 you correct but still shows tweets with Alex only. it didnt show me any other keywords even after deleting "Alex" from the main list, coz we give it directly in the cod, and running your code the tweets i still get are only with Alex

Comment: Do you mean tweet with Alex but no other keywords are showing?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88  Exactly!